# how to check is location service enabled in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, geolocation, nuxt.js

my application in nuxt and i want just check is location service is enabled or else if not enabled then trigger modal show decent message.

```
<b-modal id="show-ask-location" hide-footer>
      <template v-slot:modal-title>
        Please Allow your location for best results
      </template>

      <b-button class="mt-3" block @click="getCurrentLocation"
        >Click here to allow location</b-button
      >
    </b-modal>
```

else it should not trigger modal `this.$bvModal.show('show-ask-location');`

i can't find any tutorial or documentation about this please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you component, use a computed property to detect geolocation:

```
...
computed: {
    canGeolocate() {
        return !!navigator.geolocation
    }
}
...
```

And use it in everywhere in your template with `v-if="canGeolocate"`.